# BootstrapClassLoader not loading in the Delegation Model

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I am just revisiting the JVM concepts and was try to do a delegation check. Consider the below code

```
public class SrkDelegationDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("ClassLoader is " + cl);
      ClassLoader parent = cl.getParent();
      if (parent == null) {
        System.out.println("Last Classloader which has no parent = " + cl);
        // This line should print Bootstrap
        break;
      }
      cl = parent;
    }
}
```

**Output**

> ClassLoader is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@ab770638
>   ClassLoader is sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@75c10082
>   Last Classloader which has no parent = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@75c10082

I am expecting the BootstrapClassLoader as well from what I've read online, not sure of this. 
I am using `adopt-openjdk-with-openj9-jvm` and JDK version is `jdk8u212-b03`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap class loader has no corresponding `java.lang.ClassLoader` object; its implementation is inside JVM. Otherwise who will load `java.lang.ClassLoader` class?

As the specification of [`ClassLoader.getParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getParent()) says,

> Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class
>   loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this
>   class loader's parent is the bootstrap class loader.

OpenJDK is exactly such implementation.